# JMSSerializationBundle can't serialize on attributes based on groups

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, jmsserializerbundle

I am trying to serialize based on the groups that I have specified on my Product class. The full product class can be seen [here](http://pastie.org/8029416). Here's the code that I am using following the example on the documentation [here](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies):

```
  $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
        $result = $serializer->serialize($param, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('marketplace')));
```

So `$param` above is essentially an array of Product objects.

However, for some reason this still outputs all of the Product attribute that I don't want (i.e: attribute that belongs to other groups not 'marketplace'). For example the attribute 'description'. I've marked description to be in the 'detail' group, but why is it still being returned as a part of the response when I asked for the 'marketplace' group?

```
/**
 * @Groups({"detail"}) 
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=350)
 */
protected $description;
```

Comment: Are you sure that your serializer service is JMSSerializer?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `@ExclusionPolicy("none")` annotation.

Comment: Just did and it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You need use `@ExclusionPolicy("all")` for class and `@Expose` for each field you want to serialize.